# How many screenshot in unity to render a video in blender with which settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I've got bad results trying to render video from unity game.

I imagined (and I could be easily wrong) that I need to capture screen every 33ms to get nearly 30 images for Blender. I first tried to record when playing the game in unity and my game display tab is on 16:9 aspect ratio and well I got the result far from what I thought (bad quality).

I further built the game and run the game choosing 1280x1024 resolution. I wanted 1920x1080, but I don't understand how to get this, because in [CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html) of unity documentation the last parameter seems to be about "how much bigger to do", but I could not figure out "related to what exactly". I tried to play with it going 4 and 8 and I could not control the result.

I recorded 90 images of 1280x1024 and added to Blender in video editing perspective/view. I found myself confused that when adding images, what should I choose from the left side-bar in Start-frame, and End-frame! I get confused as I don't know if to count every picture a frame or not. If yes, then 90 images must produce 3s video, which I failed to get!

Back to Blender, the settings I change:

1. File format: H.264
2. Encoding: Preset H.264 (format)
3. Resolution/Quality to 100% (it is X:1920, Y:1080)
4. Start frame: 1
5. End frame: ??? (anything I get ends to unexpected result)
6. Frame rate: 30

Other than output path and file name, I didn't change anything else. What I get is nearly 3s video but the character movements are not realistic, it looks like forwarding fast the video.

How I can achieve a good result or point me to where to read what that could help me understand what to do in terms of obtaining screen shots from unity and what setting in blender?

Comment: How is the documentation unclear? `When superSize parameter is larger than 1, a larger resolution screenshot will be produced. For example, passing 4 will make the screenshot be 4x4 larger than it would normally be`

Comment: "a larger resolution screenshot will be produced.", my expectation is a formula/function, where I right at once see "if I input 2 to that, I get HD image. Reading above, all I know is "larger to What you generated with the default value", still not telling much to me. I also do not like the word "normally" there, I'm seeking numbers everywhere. I can't claim that above documentation statement is in "ideal" state, maybe you can. Sorry I'm not a power user and I do not really believe that documentation is only for power users.

Comment: Uh... "**passing 4** will make the screenshot be **4x4 larger** than it would normally be." (that is, 4 times taller and 4 times wider). If you don't know how big "normal" is, that would be *the size of the game window:* 1 pixel per pixel.

Comment: Thank you, these sure are obvious (as you see in my question, I gave to what resolution I open my game window, which is for this point in doc) and not main point of my question (which is a workflow for how to get HD video form unity-blender). I expected that I could have a method in unity, by which I could request an in-memory render of images to the XY dimension I specify, like simply specifying 1920, 1080 and have unity just render them out. Anyway thanks.

Comment: It's...a screen shot...it captures what is available at the resolution it's available at. It wouldn't make sense for an 800x600 application to request a 1600x900 pixel "capture."

Comment: True, that's why I looked for something different where I can get in-memory render at the resolution in demand, but until now I don't know anything like that. I'm looking for a workflow to get video trailer of the game (I know about existing plugins, I'm trying to learn to make my own).

Comment: That's what [Render Textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) are for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to!